# How to deploy nodejs, angularjs and apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on the [seed](https://github.com/gocreating/seed) project now

I want to use

`nodejs` as `api server` listening on port `5001`,

`express` as back-end framework,

`angularjs` as front-end framework,

and `apache` as `static file server` (such as lots of .js file that angular requires) listening on port `5000`

---

In angular, I have configuration below

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

---

As for apache, I add the following configuration to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
Listen 5000

<VirtualHost *:5000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/seed/public
    <Directory /var/www/seed/public >
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also add `/public/.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # support angular
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /#!/$1 
</IfModule>
```

The current rewrite rule is for angular, because it needs a hashbang when a user refresh the page

---

Now I don't know how to redirect api request with URL starting with `/api` to port `5001`

Is it possible to do this with `.htaccess` file?

And is there any better way to cooperate with nodejs, angularjs and apache?

I couldn't find any tutorial about this kind of combination...

Thanks for reading or answering my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a reverse proxy configuration in Apache. Ensure firstly that mod_proxy is installed and available.

Then configure your Apache virtual host like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
  Order deny, allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
<Location /api>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:5001
  ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:5001
</Location>
```

HTH